# Multiplying two keys in a list (in a dictionary) and finding average

Tags: python

Attempting to multiply each item quantity by the price and then find the total average price of all items bought.

```
shopping_cart = {
    "tax": .08,
    "items": [
        {
            "title": "orange juice",
            "price": 3.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "rice",
            "price": 1.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "beans",
            "price": 0.99,
            "quantity": 3
        },
        {
            "title": "chili sauce",
            "price": 2.99,
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "title": "chocolate",
            "price": 0.75,
            "quantity": 9
        }
    ]
}


total = sum(val[-1] * sum[-2] for val in shopping_cart.values())

print(total)
```

Error states float is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like what skymon said, but he is averaging over total items in the dict, rather than using 'quantity'. Try something like this?

```
total_price = sum([item['price'] * item['quantity'] for item in shopping_cart['items']])
total_items = sum([item['quantity'] for item in shopping_cart['items']])
average_price_per_item = total_price/total_items
```

To do this more efficiently you could only iterate the shopping cart once..

```
cost = 0
quantity = 0

for item in shopping_cart['items']:
    cost += item['price'] * item['quantity']
    quantity += item['quantity']

average_cost = cost/quantity
```

Comment: Your total_items is missing a closing ) but other than that it worked perfectly. Thank you. I am still sorting out how to deal with lists inside dictionaries.

Comment: That second answer looks like what I was attempting to do when I first looked at the problem. My syntax was just off. That is super helpful.

Comment: Thanks, fixed the bracket

Comment: would you say that the for loop is a "better" way to do it?

Comment: Yes @JeffR I would, it's readable, and will perform better if you end up with a lot of items in your cart. Its also worth noting, you may want to cast one of cost or quantity to float explicitly in the average_cost calculation, just to make it safe in case all your prices are whole numbers

Answer (score 0):

You need to access each item in the dict, so you could do it like this:

```
shopping_cart = { "tax": .08, "items": [ { "title": "orange juice", "price": 3.99, "quantity": 1 }, { "title": "rice", "price": 1.99, "quantity": 3 }, { "title": "beans", "price": 0.99, "quantity": 3 }, { "title": "chili sauce", "price": 2.99, "quantity": 1 }, { "title": "chocolate", "price": 0.75, "quantity": 9 } ] }

total = sum(item.get("price") * item.get("quantity") for item in shopping_cart.get("items"))
average = total / len(shopping_cart.get("items"))

print(total)
print(average)
```

This results in:

> 22.67
>
> 4.534

Comment: dang, that is pretty simple. Thank you. I am still getting familiar with how to deal with lists inside of dictionaries so I really appreciate the help.